# Exception while doing past iteration backup: Source

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on Android project. I connected my phone to Android Studio in order to test the app. After second upload `Gradle Build` failed and gave this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'.
>
> Exception while doing past iteration backup : Source /home/ziyaddin/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/build/intermediates/builds/debug/19181584762318/classes.dex and destination /home/ziyaddin/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/build/intermediates/builds/debug/19181584762318/classes.dex must be different

What can be the reason for that? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

I solved this issue by `Build -> Rebuild Project`  and then `Run` again.

<s>Also I think newly added menu `Run -> Clean and Rerun` should also fix this issue.</s>
[EDIT:] `Clean and Rerun` is removed in Android Studio 2.3

Comment: This occurred for me in Android Studio 2.2.2. Clean and Rerun did not work, but Rebuild Project did.

Comment: killer, perfect.  UPVOTED #100 :)

Comment: Can someone please explain the problem behind this error message? Filenames are the same, one file must be different to itself? It's hard to understand why more effort must be done instead of simply having the debug button do what it says.

Comment: For me, 1st I had to clear the debug folder as mentioned by **Anirudh Sharma** below and then `Build -> Rebuild`.

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered same issue, it solved by rebuilding the project.

```
Build-> Rebuild Project
```

and then

```
Run
```

I think this is only occuring on new Android Studio update from 2.0.

Answer (score 9):

I have this problem and solved by removing all directory (or only one) from directory   **../app/build/intermediates/builds/debug/**.

in this example: **/home/ziyaddin/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/build/intermediates/builds/debug/19181584762318**

Answer (score 6):

i solved this by invalidating cache, Rebuilding the project, and then running it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to take:

1. select Build
2. Select Rebuild project
3. run project

Answer (score 2):

I have just had this issue, and solved by unplugging my phone and running in the emulator. This built okay, and then subsequent tests on my phone were successful. In doing this, I also commented out my savedInstanceState Bundle, which may have been a contributing factor. I think this is potentially an internal glitch with Android Studio.

Steps to take:

1. Comment out Bundles/Saved States
2. Run on Emulator only
3. Retry with Phone
4. Add back Bundles/Saves States
   5) Try running on device again, all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild project works fine in Android Studio 2.2.2